# How to compute all inequivalent (under Aut(P)) nonnegative integer weight assignments (with fixed sum) to the vertices of a finite poset P?

Tags: combinatorics, dag, partial-order, group-theory, topology

Let $P$ be a poset on $n$ points, $\text{Aut}(P)$ its automorphism group, and $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k$ the lengths of the orbits under $\text{Aut}(P)$.

**Goal:** An algorithm to generate a member from each equivalence class (under $\text{Aut}(P)$) of assignments of nonnegative integer weights to the vertices of $P$ such that the weights sum to $m.$

**Partial result:** My current algorithm works for $m+n\leq5$ and only misses a tiny fraction of weight assignments for larger values of $m+n.$ For example, for $m+n=6,7,8$ just $1,7,57$ out of $400,2490,18980$ are missed, respectively.

For $m+n=6$ it only fails to distinguish between these two inequivalent weight assignments (black $=0,$ red $=1)$:

[image: poset on 4 points]

**The algorithm:** Let $C_{i,j}$ and $P_{i,j}$ be the sets of compositions and partitions, respectively, of $i$ with $j$ nonnegative parts. We assign all compositions in $C_{m,k}$ to the set of orbits (one part per orbit) and to each such composition $c_1+c_2+\dots+c_k,$ all possible combinations of partitions $p_{i,1}+\dots+p_{i,a_i}\in P_{c_i,a_i}$ (one part per vertex) for $1\leq i\leq k.$

Since $\text{Aut}(P)=\{(1), (0\ 1)(2\ 3)\}$ for the poset $P$ in the diagram above, its orbits are $\{0,1\}$ and $\{2,3\}.$ Our algorithm fails to recognize it matters whether we select vertex $2$ or $3$ to go with vertex $0,$ assuming $0$ was selected from $\{0,1\}$ under the composition $1+1$ of $m$ and its only possible combination of subpartitions, namely, $1+0$ for each orbit.

The theme gets repeated as we increase $n$:

[image: posets on 6 points]

Most if not all (I haven't checked) of the missing weight assignments for $m+n\leq8$ can be obtained by symmetrically removing edges and vertices from these two posets. Note that the one on the right is self-dual.

**The backstory:** A year and a half ago I posted [this message](https://mailman.anu.edu.au/pipermail/nauty/2019-November/000852.html) to Brendan McKay's [nauty](https://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/) mailing list asking about the availability of nonhomeomorphic finite topologies online. As per his reply, McKay generously sent me files containing all transitive digraphs on up to 9 points, from which I was able to easily—using his detailed and easy-to-follow instructions—produce all nonhomeomorphic topologies on up to $9$ points (available [here](https://www.mathtransit.com/finite_topological_spaces.php)).

Unfortunately, he did not mention how to construct the digraphs and I didn't ask. His and Brinkmann's paper [Counting Unlabelled Topologies and Transitive Relations](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL8/McKay/mckay170.html) enumerates them (see the proof of Theorem 2.1) but it doesn't show how to construct them as far as I can tell. The insufficient, so-close-yet-so-far algorithm above was inferred from McKay's digraphs. Maybe the vertices need to be partitioned (colored); that would refine the orbits, which at least seems to be on the right track.

**Closing remarks:** An MSE cross-post appears [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4142744/how-to-compute-all-equivalence-classes-of-weight-assignments-to-the-vertices-of). My overall goal is to add cardinalities $10$ and $11$ to my collection of nonhomeomorphic topologies. The latter file will be approximately 10 GB uncompressed in adjacency matrix format. I might also post a brief note on my ResearchGate page describing the method of construction.

Comment: Triple-posting on MO produced an answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/393915/5090